# Mixing different forms of a noun in a paragraph?

Tags: tense, nouns, tense-agreement

I am sking if it is allowed to mix the singular form, the plural form, and "the + n" form of a noun within a paragraph, and whether the meaning changes at all.

For example, are both (1) and (2) correct and are there any differences between them?

(1) **Tigers** are wild animals that live in the jungle. **A tiger** has black stripes on its skin and **the tiger is** not a social animal like **lions**.

(2) **The tiger** is a wild animal that lives in the jungle. **Tigers** have black stripes on their skins and **tigers are** not a social animal like **the lion**.

Similarly, are both (3) and (4) correct and are there any differences between them?

(3) The tiger **is a wild animal** that lives in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on the **skins** and tigers are not **a social animal** like the lion.

(4) The tiger is **wild animals** that live in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on the **skin** and **tigers are** not **social animals** like the lion.

Comment: There's no need to repeat nouns like this in those sentences. It makes them sound repetitive and tedious.  Try something like this instead: "Tigers are wild animals that live in the jungle, have black stripes on their fur, but are not social animals like lions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use sentences with different tenses in a single paragraph.  However, match verb and subject count, avoid making unnecessary repetitions of the subject or putting too many clauses in one sentence.

So:

> (1) Tigers are wild animals that live in the jungle. A tiger has black
> stripes on its skin and the tiger is not a social animal like lions.

Tigers are wild animals that live in the jungle. A tiger has black stripes on its skin. **Unlike the lion, the tiger is not a social animal**.

> (2) The tiger is a wild animal that lives in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on their skins and tigers are not a social animal like the lion.

The tiger is a wild animal that lives in the jungle. **They** have black stripes on their **skin**.  **Unlike lions, they are not social animals.**

> (3) The tiger is a wild animal that lives in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on the skins and tigers are not a social animal like the lion.

The tiger is a wild animal that lives in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on **their skin**. **Unlike the lion, a tiger is not a social animal.**

> (4) The tiger is wild animals that live in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on the skin and tigers are not social animals like the lion.

**Tigers are wild animals** that live in the jungle. Tigers have black stripes on **their** skin.  **Unlike the lion, tigers are not social animals.**

All of the above are fine and do not differ in meaning.   But the sentences are just a little too simple to sound natural.  In English, it is often better to put an adjective in an existing sentence to describe a subject than to start a whole new sentence.  It is also good to remove prepositional phrases that do not add meaning, and avoid non-parallel noun phrases where possible (see Kate's comment below).

So, consider saying:

**Tigers are black-striped, wild animals that live in the jungle. Unlike lions, they are not social animals.**

Comment: So besides being too rudimentary, the original sentences (1) and (2) are both correct and do not differ in meaning; and the same goes for (3) and (4)?

Comment: If you are comparing tigers and lions, it would be better to use both nouns in the same form - "The tiger is not a social animal like _the lion_" OR "Tigers... lions".

Comment: @ASlowLearner - Exactly.

Comment: @KateBunting - I totally concur.  I edited the answer to draw attention to this.